# entity framework cannot get results of a many to many relationship

Tags: entity-framework

I was trying to explore Code First today when I ran into a weird situation. I created 3 tables and entity framework created a 4th table for my many-to-many relationship. the code is as below:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace pizza_test.models
{
    public class Pizza
    {

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public float Price { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public int IngredientId { get; set; }
        public virtual IList<Bottom> Bottoms { get; set; }
        public virtual IList<Ingredient> Ingredients { get; set; }

    }
}


using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace pizza_test.models
{
    public class Bottom
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Size { get; set; }
        public virtual Pizza Pizzas { get; set; }
    }
}



using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace pizza_test.models
{
    public class Ingredient
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public virtual Pizza Pizzas { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The code of my dbcontext is as follows:

```
namespace pizza_test
{
    using models;
    using System;
    using System.Data.Entity;
    using System.Linq;

    public class PizzaContext : DbContext
    {

        public PizzaContext()
            : base("name=PizzaContext")
        {
        }

        public DbSet<Pizza> Pizza { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Ingredient> Ingredient { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Bottom> Bottom { get; set; }
    }
}
```

However when I try to query the database in my program.cs I am not allowed to call item.Ingredients.Name .

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var _context = new PizzaContext();

        var firstPizza = _context.Pizza.Include(p => p.Ingredients).ToList();
        foreach (var item in firstPizza)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.Ingredients.Name);
        }
    }
}
```

Which makes me kind of lost since i thought this was the power of ORMs. Did i forget something here? Also when i debug it in Visual Studio I can find all the related data of Ingredients including name, description and id. Thanks for any help provided.

Comment: probably because of your virtual keys, try setting lazy loading off

Comment: `context.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;`

Comment: Or use `.include()` in your querys, either way make sure it is eagerly loaded

Comment: Poor variable naming - `firstPizza` is `List<Pizza>`, `item` is `Pizza`. Also  `item.Ingredients` is `IList<Ingredient>`, and lists do not have name, description, id etc., their elements do. Try `foreach`-ing the `item.Ingredients` and you'll get an access to the properties you need. Also I don't see many-to-many relationship - naming 2 properties of type `Pizza` `Pizzas` does not make them many.